# Issues with "Site to Zone Assignment List" working and then not working

Tags: group-policy

I'm not a domain expert so I apologize if some of my lingo is off.

I'm trying to make it so that users on my domain don't need to enter a username/password when accessing a specific website.  I've done this via a group policy under UserConfiguration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Page\Site to Zone Assignment List.

In the Site to Zone Assignment List I've added the ip address of the website, and set the zone to '1'.

The weird thing is, when a user first logs onto their computer and the policy is updated on the computer, it works.  But after about an hour, the policy seems to disappear and users are prompted for a username/password when they access the website.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.